# Prove f is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be such that $|f '(x)|\leq B$ for some $B\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Not exactly sure how to prove this.

Comment: Functions with a bounded derivative imply the function is lipschitz continuous implies the function is uniformly continuous.  You can google proofs of either of those implications :)

Comment: lipschitz function. use the limit definition of the derivative

Answer (score 2):

$f$ will even be Lipschitz continuous, which is stronger than uniformly continuous.

**Hint:** Mean-value Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Given $\epsilon>0$ let us choose $\delta=\epsilon/B$. Then, if $|x-y|<\delta$ we have  $$\underbrace{|f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(c)(x-y)|}_{\text{For some $c\in(x,y)$, by the Mean Value Theorem.}}\leq B|x-y|<B\delta=\epsilon.$$